# Adding or subtracting a number of days to a datetime column using df.query

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am working to use the below while DATE_1 and DATE_2 are Datetime type

```
df.query('DATE_1 < DATE_2 - 10')
```

also tried the below

```
td = pd.Timedelta(days=10)

df.query('DATE_1 < DATE_2 - @td')
```

both the above didnt work

Please suggest

Comment: kindly provide sample data with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to express this condition as a *query*, even when the number
of days is in a variable.

Run:

```
n = 10
df.query('DATE_2.sub(DATE_1).dt.days > @n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I assum you changed the column to the datetime data type already. If you haven't you can do by `df['DATE_1]=pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_1'])` and do the same for other column also.

```
td= pd.Timeddelta(days=10)
df['DATE_1']<(df['DATE_2']-td)
```